# How do I specify the licensing query parameter for the Microsoft Teams API when using the Microsoft Graph SDK for Java?

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

According to the [Licensing and payment requirements for the Microsoft Teams API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-licenses) documentation, I need to include a `model` query parameter to specify the
licensing and payment model for the Microsoft Teams API. How do I do this when using the [Microsoft Graph SDK for Java](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java)?

I currently access the Graph API using the `com.microsoft.graph.requests.GraphServiceClient` class:

```
public static GraphServiceClient<Request> getGraphClient(@NonNull final AadAuthenticationProperties properties,
                                                             @NonNull final String tenantId) {
        var credential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder().clientId(properties.getCredential().getClientId())
                                                            .clientSecret(properties.getCredential().getClientSecret())
                                                            .tenantId(tenantId)
                                                            .build();
        var authProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(
                properties.getAuthorizationClients().get("graph").getScopes(), credential);

        final var logger = new DefaultLogger();
        logger.setLoggingLevel(LoggerLevel.DEBUG);

        return GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider(authProvider).logger(logger).buildClient();
    }
```

Is there someway that I should alter this client? Would this only be necessary for subscribing to change notifications? While for querying for all object details? While querying for certain particular object details?

Answer (score 1):

Code Snippet that might help, the following is for getAllMessages model A.

You can modify it as per your needs but the underlying logic remains the same.

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
{
    new QueryOption("model", "A")
};

var getAllMessages = await graphClient.Users["Alexw@cqons.onMicrosoft.com"].Chats
    .GetAllMessages()
    .Request( queryOptions )
    .GetAsync();
```

For all future readers, you can query this in Graph Explorer and go to the code snippet section to get the corresponding code snippet.

Comment: I took your advice and successfully added the model parameter to the graph client request.  However, this newly found documentation seems to contradict your advice, indicating that the model should be supplied in the request body.  As I see that you're a Graph API Support Engineer, might you have any clarification about this?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-example

Comment: @dhalsim2 The documentation is correct and it is not conflicting, while you create the subscription you cannot specify the model in the query because you are not using the Models on Subscription endpoint. You are using the model on Teams API. The resource part of the request body indicates which resource you going to use so in this case you're using team API model A. since the resource type is asked in the body you need to pass the model parameter as the body. This holds true while creating the subscriptions only.   In nutshell Subscription endpoint doesn't support query parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification about the subscription endpoint.  If I'm subscribing to `/chats/getAllMessages` and `/teams/getAllMessages`, does you comment imply that I need to supply the model when getting these objects, and not just when subscribing to change notifications?  And if so, would this apply only to resources that have special licensing and payment requirements or would I need to supply the model for other resources, such as getting all users (`/users`).  Thank you for your patience and helpfulness with my questions.

Comment: @Dhalsim2 Yes you're right, you need to specify model while using teams API which need licenses, as of now only teams API need licenses and hence for all other API's you do not need to specify any model parameter